# Tag merge request for mysql

Tags: support, retag-request

The `mysqld` and `mysqladministrator` tags are entirely superfluous.  Unfortunately, there's 14 and 25 tags respectively.  I would like to request that they be merged with the `mysql` tag.

Comment: There are now zero using `mysqladministrator`.  I'm stuck on hold with a vendor's support rep...

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like you took care of them both.

Comment: Not a problem, I was bored. Back on hold... ..ugh. :)

Answer (score 5):

I concur. The extra tags add nothing except confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqld` is the MySQL daemon, whereas `mysqladministrator` is a management interface. Two completely different things and completely distinct from the generic `mysql`. What's next, merging all Windows server tags?

Comment: mysql and mysqld are largely synonymous  in the context of the tag for all intents and purpose.  I do not see the value in separating them.  mysqladministrator tagged questions were all over the board and not pertaining mysqladmin.

Comment: Having a tag for every potential binary with UNIX software will have little benefit in most cases.

Comment: I appreciate your concern. I believe [mysqld] is synonymous with [mysql] and also [mysql-server].  The management interface tool "MySQL Administrator" has been EOL since 2009-12-18.  The replacement is known as "Database Administrator".  Perhaps a tag for the management suite that is more appropriate? [mysql-workbench]?